# How to screen print a design in Illustrator with a gaussian blur effect?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, screen-printing

I am new to the screen printing world and I have a design I'm having trouble printing the color separations for. I noticed the gaussian blur effect is not printing on the color separations. I also know that gaussian blur is not vector but raster, so I tried converting the image to bitmap to see if that would make a difference but it did not.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is doable, but I strongly recommend you contact your screen printing vendor with a proof concept to see if it would work. Even if you got the blur to print to a specific spot channel, the screen printing process does not usually play nicely with gradients or soft edges.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a halftone for the blurred image. As long as the dots are fairly large, and the bitmap is quite high resolution (like 300ppi or more), it should be good enough for screen printing. There's no need to make the halftone vector.

Here's a quick example below:  I blurred a black circle in Photoshop in greyscale mode, and then converted it to a bitmap using the halftone option. I copied and pasted it into Illustrator and chose a spot colour for it. And then stuck some vector work on top.

[image]